# Migrate kafka schema-registry to new kafka-cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We are performing migration of our kafka cluster (creating the new one and migrating all topics, consumers, producers there). We have schema-registry in old cluster and want to move it to use the new cluster.

Is there any way to copy schemas (with the same IDs) to new cluster or any other way to migrate schema-registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_schemas` topic is simply JSON data which you can mirror over to the new Kafka Cluster.